# CSS / HTML <a href not working on handheld devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

Website:  http://www.werk-build.com/

I have multiple nav buttons that perform correctly on computer browsers, but for some reason the link is inactive on all handheld devices.  I have used this similar code for another website without any issues.

On an iPhone for instance if you click button, the link highlights (as it should) but does not go to href.  Now if you hold down on button the iOS will bring up a command prompt to allow you to open in a new page (which works) or open (which does not).

Any help would be appreciated!

CSS:

```
.nav_button01 {
position: absolute;
width: 8px;
height: 16px;
left: 347px;
top: 3px;
color: #666;
border: 1px;
vertical-align: middle;
border-style: solid;
animation: a:hover;
z-index: 50;
}

.nav_button01:hover {
color: #2282AC;
background-color: #2282AC;
}   

.nav_button01:active {
color: #2282AC;
background-color: #2282AC ;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.werk-build.com/4FOUNDATIONS1.html" target="_parent"><div class="nav_button01" title="Victorian Rehab"></div></a>
```

Thanks.

DSM

Comment: That formatting is only for HTML5, did you make sure to add the HTML5 doctype at the top and check if your mobile browser supports HTML5? Otherwords you may have to do this: `<div><a>...</a></div>`

Comment: Could you try out one thing please? Comment out the hover CSS for a second and try then again. If that works I could explain to you what happens there.